# How to create string with URL

Tags: android, xml

Try to create a string with URL, and this works incorrectly.

```
<string name="aboutSourceOkHttp"><a href="http://square.github.io/retrofit/">Retrofit</a> от Square</string>
<string name="aboutSourceAliceFont">Шрифт <a href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alice">Alice</a> от Ксении Ерулевич</string>
<string name="aboutSourceCite">Цитаты от <a href="http://forismatic.com/">forismatic.com</a></string>
```

First and second item don't allow me to open browser. Third works fine? I can't understand where is my mistake.

P.S.
I try do it by string.xml and don't want to do programmaticaly.

Comment: How are you using them?  By default Android does not use HTML, you need to jump through hoops to do that.  You won't get a solution that's just strings.xml

Comment: 1) First link : Does on server retrofit/ directory contains index.xxx....? And your url is incomplete..!! 2) Second link... Again URL is incorrect and does Alice/ directory contains index.xxx...? 3) Third link... Does this servers public html directory holds index.xxx....???????? Again this url is incomplete too..!!